# How to get browser active tab URL in node/electron app on Linux/Mac/Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, firefox, electron

I am looking for a smart way to get active browser URL for a cross-platform electron app. I have found a solution using AppleScript for Mac OS Safari and Chrome but still no solution for Firefox, Windows, and Linux :(

A solution for Chrome and Safari on MacOS using AppleScript:

Using [node-applescript](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-applescript) I was able to get safari and chrome URLs. Unfortunately, Firefox does not support AppleScript and the way to obtain the URL is hacky and unusable in production. Also, I still have no clue how to get the URLs on Linux and Windows.

```
const scripts = {
  'chrome': `tell application "Google Chrome" to get URL of active tab of front window as string`,
  'vivaldi': `tell application "Vivaldi" to return URL of active tab of front window`,
  'safari': `tell application "Safari" to return URL of front document as string`,
  'firefox': `tell application "Firefox" to activate
  tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "l" using command down
    keystroke "c" using command down
  end tell
  delay 0.5
  return the clipboard`,
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for this ...

Comment: I am afraid not. Still looking...

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution?

Comment: any one has solution for this

Answer (score 1):

For Linux try command wmctrl. if there is no title tag on the web page, wmctrl should show you full url in the title bar.