# Track which browser app and url is currently active on Windows

Tags: windows, electron, etw, change-tracking, wfp

We have an Electron app that runs on Windows, and Linux. We want to track which browser app and url is currently active. How to achieve it? There are solutions available to track app and URL on macOS. But we specifically need to add support for Windows and Linux.

Any idea if mitmproxy or wireshark is a right way to move forward? Does Windows Automation API solve the problem?

I tried using [active-win](https://github.com/sindresorhus/active-win) and [x-win](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@miniben90/x-win). They are able to track the URL on macOS but not on Windows.

[How to get browser active tab URL in node/electron app on Linux/Mac/Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510161/how-to-get-browser-active-tab-url-in-node-electron-app-on-linux-mac-windows) didn't help much.

Comment: It should be possible to enumerate all windows and search for address bars periodically via UI Automation APIs. But that is a costly undertaking. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview